# C++ MySQL Sql syntax error while syntax is correct

Tags: c++, mysql, file-io

my C++ program reads a file with sql query and tries to execute it. When I execute the query using phpmyadmin, it works, but when executed in my program, it ends up with the following error:
[image: SQL Syntax error]

Code:

```
    ifstream create_file ("create.sql");

    if (create_file.is_open())
    {
        char * create;
        int length;

        create_file.seekg (0, ios::end);
        length = create_file.tellg();
        create_file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        create = new char [length];
        create_file.read (create,length);
        create_file.close();

        cout << "Executing query: " << endl;
        cout.write (create,length);
        cout << "EOF query" << endl;
        if(mysql_query(mysql, "CREATE DATABASE grant_db")) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create database: Error: %s\n",
              mysql_error(mysql));
        }
        if(mysql_select_db(mysql, "grant_db")) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select database: Error: %s\n",
              mysql_error(mysql));
        }
        if(mysql_query(mysql, create)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create table: Error: %s\n",
              mysql_error(mysql));
            mysql_query(mysql, "DROP DATABASE grant_db");
        }

        delete[] create;
    } else cout << "Unable to open file 'create.sql'.";
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: May be both the drivers are behaving differently, can you try removing the comments from your query and see if that works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put multiple statements in a single mysql_query call. You need to execute them one at a time, by default at least. See the [mysql_query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-query.html) docs.

Comment: After adding the "CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS" parameter works perfectly. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be that it doesn't handle the `/* ... */` comments. Try using `--` comments instead.